# How to connect 14 guage speaker wire to LED light strips?

Tags: wiring, led, low-voltage, connectors

I am installing 12v undercabinet led light strips in my kitchen. I have in-wall 14-2 speaker wire and I'd like to use this to connect a 4 short runs (8 ft total) of LED light strips. Most of the solderless connectors for LED slight strip application seem to be for using 22 or 18 gauge wire.

I'd like to use the 14 gauge wires, but can't seem to find a good way to attach the wires to the light strips without soldering them.

Perhaps I am missing something in my search. I am looking for possible solutions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What wire size is coming out of the led fixtures?

Comment: @JACK They are LED light strips, which as far as I know use solderless connectors like this:   https://www.amazon.com/dp/B07TQ1ZCYX/ref=cm_sw_r_tw_dp_8GRHWVXTVTNS30JBYCE8

Comment: Just to be clear; These wires are from the voltage transformer to the LED's and NOT from a 120v source to the voltage transformer. ?

Comment: @AlaskaMan yes this is all low voltage, coming from a transformer putting out 12v and 3 amps. Hoping to do a single run since I've got 4 lengths of lights. (~ 2', 2', 3', and 1')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several types of reducer insulated crimp connectors that can be used for this. The one shown below is for #14-16 to #18-22. This will fit through holes that you might have to drill going from cabinet to cabinet. These will work for your 12 volt runs but don't even think about splicing your 120 volt runs. This crimping tool is inexpensive and can be used for many different connectors. You might have to get your plugs and add some #18 to 20 gauge wire to them and then splice to your #14. You also could remove some strands of your speaker wire so it fits into the plugs. You could never do this with any household 120/240 volt wiring but would be OK for the 12 volt led fixtures

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a choice.

### You *have* to use fine wires like #22.

If you don't, then "the tail will wag the dog" -- the wires will be so much stiffer than the LED strip that the wire will not be able to follow the LED strip to where it's got to go - either it will tear the LED strip out of position or tear the connecter off the LED trip.

Since a 2' segment of *double density* monochrome LED strip only draws 0.5A, it's certainly no problem for the #22 wire.

That thin lead only needs to be a foot or two. After that, you can wire-nut it into #14 or whatever.